# avoid grouping on empty values RDLC

Tags: expression, rdlc, ssrs-grouping

I have a column group on a datafield. I need to group only when there is a value in the field. Right now it groups on the NULL field too.

I have tried the following group expressin:

```
=Fields!ScaleName.Value <> "" OR Fields!ScaleName.Value <> Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this problem using a Group Filter (right click on group > `Group Properties` > `Filters`):

- expression: `=IsNothing(Fields!ScaleName.Value)`
- type: `Boolean`
- operator: `=`
- value: `=False`